# Significance Of Small Sets With Arbitrarily Long Progressions?

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

Does the existence of a small set with arbitrarily long arithmetic progressions (ALPs) imply that there exist large sets without any progressions at all? We can construct an example of a small set with ALPs by first choosing a reference set which we know to be small (in this case $( \frac{1}{n!} )_{n \geq 1}$) and a fixed common difference of $1$ for all known progressions in our sequence. Beginning with the largest sequence of consecutive positive integers such that

$$\frac{1}{k} + \frac{1}{k+1} + \frac{1}{k+2} < \frac{1}{1!}$$

we find that $k=3$. Therefore, the first three terms of our small set are $\{ 3, 4, 5, \ldots \}$. The sum of the reciprocals of the next four terms should be less than $\frac{1}{2!}$, i.e.

$$\frac{1}{7}+\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{9}+\frac{1}{10} < \frac{1}{2!}.$$

Etc. etc.

Comment: Did you try thinking about it?  Did you attempt any constructions?  How did they work?

Comment: I did find one, which is why I was curious that I couldn't find one elsewhere.

Comment: "Why didn't other people write down this example I found (but haven't described)?" is not a math question.

Comment: I was just thinking that if it's an easy task to construct such a sequence, why are there no examples listed anywhere?

Comment: Thanks for editing, this is a much better question now than it was originally.

Comment: Although I'm not sure what "without any progressions at all" means

Comment: Technically they would be Salem-Spencer sets.